# How to center all tables in Word, coming from Excel - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, center

I'm very new to VBA and my first code is to copy excel tables and paste it at word. It's working, but the problem is that all tables are pasted left-aligned and I want it **center** aligned. Does anyone knows how to do it? Going  to post my code here:

```
Sub excel2word()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
'Copy the range Which you want to paste in a New Word Document
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")


For i = 2 To 200
 With objWord
    .Documents.Add     
    Sheets("Plan2").Select
    Range("A" & i).Copy
    .Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
    .Selection.TypeParagraph

    Sheets("Teste").Select        
    Range(Cells((26 * (i - 1) + 1), 1).Address, Cells(((26 * (i - 1) + 7)), 3).Address).Copy
    .Selection.PasteExcelTable True, False, False
    .Visible = True
    .Selection.TypeParagraph

    Sheets("Teste").Select
    Range(Cells((26 * (i - 1) + 8), 1).Address, Cells(((26 * (i - 1) + 16)), 3).Address).Copy
    .Selection.PasteExcelTable True, False, False
    .Visible = True
    .Selection.TypeParagraph

    Sheets("Teste").Select
    Range(Cells((26 * (i - 1) + 17), 1).Address, Cells(((26 * (i - 1) + 25)), 3).Address).Copy
    .Selection.PasteExcelTable True, False, False
    .Visible = True
    .Selection.TypeParagraph

End With
 Next


 End Sub
```

As you can see, this code copy paste 3 tables at one interaction, that is 600 tables in total! So, it gets very boring to center one by one.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to center the table on the page, or center the data in the cells?

Comment: Oddly, and as you have probably already realized, Word doesn't seem to provide a VBA method for aligning the table as a whole. In fact, if you turn on the macro recorder and then use align, you get a different behavior than if you align without the macro recorder on. However, you can apply a table style which provides this alignment. Is creating a style in Word an option for you? If so, I think i can provide the code. (I think you'd need to create the style outside of VBA, and then use VBA to apply it).

Comment: Wow, yes, I use the already existing table styles (is that what you are talking about?) If not, I dont know what you are referring. 
And yes, the macro recorder for word is way different from excel, that is much more easier. I tried so many times to align the table using macro recorder and sometimes it worked (align the whole table), but it wasn't usefull because I have to select tables one by one and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still needs it:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm going to try to explain how I would do the first part of this. The first part is outside of VBA. In Word, you can create or modify table styles. Since you say you are using existing styles, you can modify them so that the table is centered. Let's say you are using the Light Shading table style (this is the first Table Style that I see when I expand Table Styles from the ribbon). Do the following:

- In a Word document, create a basic table. You can just click Insert Table from the Insert tab and insert a table with a couple cells.
- Select the table. You should see the Table Tools tabs appear on the ribbon. Click Design.
- You should see some table styles in the center of the ribbon. Find the one you need (expanding the dropdown if necessary), and right-click.
- Select Modify Table Style from the context menu.
- The Modify Style dialog will pop up.
- Click Format and then Table Properties. Under the Table tab in the Table Properties dialog, look for Alignment. Choose Center and click OK. Click OK again to save the change.

Now, when you apply that table style to a standard table the table will be centered.

The second part, if necessary, is to apply that style programatically. I don't have time to write that part out right now, but I can edit this later. Perhaps this will be a starting point for you, though.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, gonna test it! But i'm quite in a hurry now! but thanks a lot